# On a SecureField in SwiftUI How do you remove the password fill box on OSX?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, combine

[image]

I cannot figure out how to remove this Passwords autofill box in SwiftUI when building for macOS.  I have tried different kinds of textContentType but nothing gets rid of this box.  It is blocking my attempt to login to my app from a return press.  Both the onCommit, or the keyboardShortcut modifier return press is being swallowed by this box.  The strange thing is, I create a blank new app with one SecureField, and the box is not there.  I am wondering if there is some kind of initial setup telling the app to use suggested passwords?  I know in the past our team looked at password autofill and supporting Associated Domains.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to prevent the "Passwords…" box from appearing on my app by making two things:

1. Passing `.username` to the `.textContentType(_:)` modifier of the email `TextField`.
2. Passing `nil` to the `.textContentType(_:)` modifier of the password `SecureField`.

I tested this solution on macOS 12.4 and Xcode 13.4.1 (13F100).

Comment: Looks like it's not working on macOS Catalyst 16.0 with Xcode version 14.2 (14C18)